# Using Union but having error with my existing column as invalid identifier

Tags: sql, union

I am using union, when wrote the query like this,

```
    SELECT tour_date AS "Departure Date",  site_name "Site Name" FROM partres, reservation, tour, site
WHERE partres.res_id = reservation.res_id
  AND reservation.tour_id = tour.tour_id
  AND tour.site_id = site.site_id
GROUP BY tour_date, site_name
HAVING COUNT(part_id) > 7

  UNION

SELECT tour_date AS "Departure Date",  site_name "Site Name"
FROM (
  SELECT res_id, (res_partcost +NVL(RES_GEARCOST,0)) AS "total_cost" 
  FROM reservation) tour, site
WHERE  reservation.tour_id = tour.tour_id
  AND tour.site_id = site.site_id
  AND total_cost > 230
GROUP BY tour_date, site_name;
```

But it displays error as

```
ORA-00904: "TOUR_DATE": invalid identifier
```

00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 305 Column: 10

so I don't know why having error with my existing column.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* no `tour_date` column coming from that sub-select in the second half of the union.

Your `tour` "table" in that case is not the actual table, but is instead the result of the inner select which only provides `res_id` and `total_cost`.

By that I mean:

```
SELECT tour_date AS "Departure Date",  site_name "Site Name"
FROM (
  SELECT res_id, (res_partcost +NVL(RES_GEARCOST,0)) AS "total_cost" 
  FROM reservation) tour, site ...
```

will give you two "tables" to get columns from. The second table is `site` which is probably where `site_name` is coming from, though you really should explicitly enforce that with `site.site_name` since it makes it more obvious.

Now this is important. Even though you *have* a real table called `tour`, the fact that your selecting from:

```
(SELECT res_id, (res_partcost +NVL(RES_GEARCOST,0)) AS "total_cost"
 FROM reservation) tour
```

means that what your query sees as `tour` is not the `tour` table. It's actually that query inside the parentheses. Hence `tour` in this case has the columns `res_id` and `total_cost`, with no `tour_date` in sight.

If you want to select things from a sub-select, you need to make sure the names match.

Comment: I don't really get that, Experts, how will it be like?

Comment: @BolorCh, hopefully my updates make it clearer. If not, you may want to ask a _different_ question specifying what you want from the tables so we can give you a query that works straight up, rather than having to figure out what you're trying to do from your query, broken as it is :-)

Comment: I posted my question in a new thread named "Can't solve this subquery, experts please help." Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825262/subquery-with-invalid-identifier-error-in-sql since the rather dubious title has been changed :-)