# Subquery with invalid identifier error in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

want to select tour date and site names in advance of total cost is more than 230 and that tour has more than 7 persons. the complete code is below, the first part of union works.

```
SELECT tour_date AS "Departure Date",  site_name "Site Name"
FROM partres, reservation, tour, site
WHERE partres.res_id = reservation.res_id
  AND reservation.tour_id = tour.tour_id
  AND tour.site_id = site.site_id
GROUP BY tour_date, site_name
HAVING COUNT(part_id) > 7

  UNION

SELECT tour_date AS "Departure Date",  site_name "Site Name"
FROM (
  SELECT res_id,tour_date,site_name, (res_partcost +NVL(RES_GEARCOST,0)) as "total_cost" 
  FROM reservation,site,tour) 
WHERE  reservation.tour_id = tour.tour_id
  AND tour.site_id = site.site_id
  AND total_cost > 230
GROUP BY tour_date, site_name;
```

I still got errors as

```
ORA-00904: "TOTAL_COST": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 437 Column: 7
```

Thanks

Comment: think you forgot to put total_cost to first SELECT statement

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? the inner query doesn't have the where clause, so you aren't joining the tables by any criteria. The fields reservation.*, tour.* and site.* are not available outside your inner query.

Comment: want to select tour date and site names in advance of total cost is more than 230 and that tour has more than 7 persons.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your join conditions inside the subquery

```
SELECT tour_date AS "Departure Date",  site_name "Site Name"
FROM (
    SELECT res_id,tour_date,site_name, (res_partcost +NVL(RES_GEARCOST,0)) as "total_cost" 
    FROM reservation,site,tour
    WHERE reservation.tour_id = tour.tour_id
    AND tour.site_id = site.site_id ) Res1
WHERE Res1.total_cost > 230 // this will not be displayed in a result
GROUP BY tour_date, site_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `union` is not going to give you an "and" between the conditions.  It is going to give you an "or" (because anything that matches either condition will be included).

I think you should phrase this as a single query, with subqueries.  Also, proper join syntax is a benefit:

```
SELECT tour_date AS "Departure Date",  site_name "Site Name"
FROM partres p join
     reservation r
     on p.res_id = r.res_id join
     tour t
     on r.tour_id = t.tour_id and
        (res_partcost + coalesce(RES_GEARCOST,0)) > 230 join
     site s
     on t.site_id = s.site_id
GROUP BY tour_date, site_name
having COUNT(part_id) > 7;
```

This version is making a guess that `total_cost` is in the `reservation` table.